# Solve for common points in a circle and curve

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

**[problem]**

I got following equation of a circle..

$x^2+y^2=9 ..(1)$

and a equation of curve as follows..

$\tan^4x + \cot^4 x + 2 =4\sin^2y....(2)$

I have to find points which satisfy both the equation..i.e points which are on the curve and inscribed inside or on the circle in common

**[ My approach]**

For solving following equation I first equate for trignometric function,So that i can obtain equation(2) in terms of x and y...Mathmetically I targeted for this.

$y=\frac {\arcsin \sqrt(\tan^4x + \cot^4 x + 2 )} 2$
 (from equation (2))

I am trying to equate $\sqrt(\tan^4x + \cot^4 x + 2 )$ in terms of $\sin a$ where "a"  is any polynomial expression ..

**[HELP]**

How should i do so..I cant break that in terms or sin function..It's going lengthy and complex . Or if any other less costly approach could be made

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For real $x,$

$$\dfrac{\tan^4x+\cot^4x}2\ge\sqrt{\tan^4x\cot^4x}=?$$

$$\implies\sin^2y\ge1\implies\sin^2y=1$$ for real$y$

Comment: did you left + sign in equation of inequilaty or multiplying tan cot??

Comment: @Raj, I have used Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: I still can't get till here....I am still confusing lot

Comment: @ShivanshuRaj, $$(\tan^2x-\cot^2x)^2\ge0$$ for real positive $\tan^2x,\cot^2x$. Following this logic, we need $$\sin^2y=1\implies\cos y=0$$ right? So, $y=?$

Comment: y became a linear equation